# Square cells layout in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am building an ios app and I need to display 8 cells in a row in landscape mode.
Also there must be 5 rows and totally 40 cells will be displayed. It must be independent of the device whether it's an iPad or iPhone, the same appearance must be delivered.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you need the cells to be square-shaped  ?

Comment: Yes, i need them to be squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jpark822's answer is right however you'll struggle with the spacing and offset of your cells.

What you could do is use a UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass:

Let's call it PrettyLayout !

```
@implementation PrettyFlowLayout

#define itemCountPerLine 8
#define itemCountPerColumn 5

-(void) prepareLayout
{
    CGFloat lineSpacing = ([self collectionViewContentSize].width - self.itemSize.width * itemCountPerLine) / (itemCountPerLine + 1);
    CGFloat interItemSpacing = ([self collectionViewContentSize].height - self.itemSize.height * itemCountPerColumn) / (itemCountPerColumn + 1);

    self.minimumLineSpacing = lineSpacing;
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = interItemSpacing;

    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(interItemSpacing, lineSpacing, interItemSpacing, lineSpacing);
}

- (CGSize)itemSize
{
    int size;

    size = (int) MIN(self.collectionView.frame.size.width / itemCountPerLine, self.collectionView.frame.size.height / itemCountPerColumn )

    return CGSizeMake((CGFloat)size, (CGFloat)size);
}

@end
```

Then all you need to do is declare an instance of PrettyLayout as the layout of your collectionview.

PS : Didn't try my code, hope it'll work

Comment: Wont work if the divided width is a decimal with it's decimal value bigger than 0.5.

Lets say your total width of the screen is 750, which divided by 8 is 93.75. If you put this as the width of a cell, the actual width will be 94px, which results in a total pixel count of 752, which means the last cell will be on the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you implement `UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource`

then assign the delegate and data source:
`myCollectionView.delegate = self;`
`myCollectionView.dataSource = self;`

then use the collectionView's datasource and delegate methods to pass it information in the view controller:

`- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
}`

`- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView`

You may want to have 5 sections of 8 items each, or just have one big section of 40

If you want to specify the size of your collection view cells, then implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`
 then you can use the delegate method:

`- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

to specify the size. this way you can set your view up such that you can have all 5 rows of 8 showing at once